# Выбрать значения, встречающиеся в обеих таблицах SQL (BigQuery)

Tags: sql

Подскажите, каким оператором нужно воспользоваться.
Имеется 2 таблицы:

```
table1          table2
clientId       clientId
    1             2
    2             3
    3             4
```

Необходимо составить запрос, чтобы получить столбец со значениями, которые встречаются в обеих таблицах:

```
clientId
   2
   3
```

**P.S.**
как обратиться к столбцу таблицы в BigQuery, если название таблицы выглядит вот так [big-query-1265:p1_Clickstream.che_magazin_2505_1207], а столбец clientId?

Comment: как обратиться к столбцу таблицы в BigQuery, если название таблицы выглядит вот так [big-query-1265:p1_Clickstream.che_magazin_2505_1207], а столбец clientId?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT table1.clientId 
FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 on table1.clientId = table2.clientId
```

P.S.

`Название таблицы.Название столбца`, но у вас какое то странное название таблицы - если оно соответствует действительности дайте ему псевдоним

```
SELECT t1.clientId 
FROM [big-query-1265:p1_Clickstream.che_magazin_2505_1207] as t1
 INNER JOIN table2 on t1.clientId = table2.clientId
```

Comment: как обратиться к столбцу таблицы в BigQuery, если название таблицы выглядит вот так [big-query-1265:p1_Clickstream.che_magazin_2505_1207], а столбец clientId?